# Shape item doesn't apply for buttons on some devices

Tags: android, xml, shapes, ring

I want to make my buttons to have ring shape with different colors. And I did it, and it is working on device, where I am debugging.
Code black_round_button.xml is located in drawable-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring">
<solid android:color="@color/black" />
```

Button code is

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button31"
  style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="@drawable/black_round_button"
  android:onClick="countClick"
  android:text="@string/zero" />
```

And on device where I debug ( Android 5.0.2) it looks good:
[black ring shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBtjM.png)

BUT!!! when I start debugging on other devices ( android 4.4.4, Android 5.1, other), I found that any of my shape ring doesn't work. it looks like:
[no black ring shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To3ii.png)

So, I have no idea why this happen. Yesterday I was testing it on 5 different devices ( 3 of them virtual, and 2 real), and only on my device it is working as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you place the xml file in the drawable-v21 folder. This is only for API >= 21! You should also have a "drawable"-folder (without the "-v21" extension), try to add the xml file in it. If the folder don't exists, just create it on the same level like the "drawable-v21"-folder.

Comment: aha, yes, When I asked this question I've also started thinking about this. Issue that in my Android studio I have them in drawable folder, but on github, they in drawable-v21. Ok, thanks for advise, will try this solution today.

Comment: you will not believe me, but it didn't help =( I moved all my xml shapes from drawable-v21 to just drawable and nothing.
Looks like I need to play with gradle and build bersions

Comment: nope , this was not a case =( I debugged it on android 6.0 with API 23, and it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 0):

So issue was reproducible not only for Android 4.4 ( API 19), issue was also reproducible for older versions like Android 6 ( API23), so issue was that my ring shapes were without necessary attributes. As I understand starting from API22 you need to add

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="17dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thickness="5dp"
android:useLevel="false">
```

This will fix issue with API22-API24.

And I am not sure that it was necessary to move xml files from drawable-v21 folder to just drawable ( because looks like ring shapes will not work in versions less than API21, you need to use "oval" for this cases, but I am not sure about this)